# Configure X11 pointerkeys

Tags: xorg, mouse, accessibility

Xorg has an option `keypad:pointerkeys` that allows keypad to be used to control pointer. I have a TKL keyboard (without numpad). Can I configure the keys that are used to control the pointer?

Comment: You'd need to work at the kernel (input layer, `evtest` etc.) level, and have the key combinations you want to use for that produce the same keyboard symbols a numeric keypad would produce. Pretty tricky to do.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to do this just by changing the keysym of the wanted keys to `KP_Left` and so on, then when enabling MouseKeys with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LeftShift</kbd>+<kbd>NumLock</kbd> the X11 server will convert use of these keys into mouse actions. Using `xkb` to do this is too complicated for me, but `xmodmap` can do this fairly easily; the problem is that any changes will be lost whenever using a `xkb` utility. To try, use `xmodmap -pk|grep '(4)'` to find the keycode for the number key `4` (which also has `$` on my keyboard):

```
   13      0x0034 (4)      0x0024 (dollar) 0x0034 (4)      0x0024 (dollar)
```

The keycode is in the first column.
You can change this to generate keypad left with `xmodmap -e 'keycode 13 = KP_Left'` (and restore it with `xmodmap -e 'keycode 13 = 4 dollar 4 dollar'`). Then try the combination to enable MouseKeys and see if the key moves the mouse. You may need to enable the option first with `setxkbmap -option keypad:pointerkeys` (which must be done before any `xmodmap`). Make sure you have some means of rebooting without using the keyboard in case the keyboard becomes unusable.

---

But these days, you can also implement your own mousekeys with tools such as `xbindkeys` which can run a command when a key is pressed, and `xdotool` which can move the mouse or click a button.

Comment: It's been more than 10 years that I haven't had a numeric keypad on my keyboard, so I haven't used the pointerkeys functionality for a long time. If memory serves, at the time my understanding was that the keypad was captured and turned into pointer movements at a very low level, without generating any keysim at all. Sorry to ask that but are you sure your answer works? Did you try it?

Comment: No, I haven't had the chance to try it out, which is why I said it *might be possible*, and provided an alternative implementation. The [xkb](https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.6/doc/kbproto/xkbproto.html) extension document seems to me to suggest that this work is being done in the extension, not the kernel.  I note that Wayland only implemented MouseKeys last year, which suggests it wasn't just a kernel toggle.

Comment: By low level, I didn't mean at the kernel level, but rather in Xorg (or XFree86 at the time), i.e. the key events are captured by the X server and turned into pointer motion events instead of key pressed events. I don't know for Wayland though, neither do I for the MouseKeys extension.